# Emacs bad indentation

Tags: init-file, indentation

So I've decided to try emacs, and I find it really good. However, I'm mostly writing Python, so the indentation is a crucial thing for me. After couple of failures in configuring I've finally reached to the point when I press ENTER, it goes to new line and automatically indents it (with TAB - size 4). Okay. But lets say I've got a function and a loop inside it. If I want emacs to indent a for loop it does it not in a proper way (for me):

```
int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
        {
            printf("lol\n");
        }
}
```

cuz I want it to be:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        printf("lol\n");
    }
}
```

My `.emacs file` looks like this:

```
(load-theme `wombat)
(setq-default standard-indent 4)
(mouse-wheel-mode t)
(setq make-backup-files nil)
(line-number-mode 1)
(setq indent-size 4)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq-default indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
(defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
(defvaralias 'cperl-indent-level 'tab-width)
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
```

Is there a way I can configure this, to make it like I want it to be?

Comment: You say you're mostly writing Python, but your examples look like they're from C++. Which is it?

Comment: Yes, it's C++, I just copied this, cuz I have a work to do for my college holiday project, and they force C++

Comment: I think you want to set your c-indentation-style to something else like `"linux"` (instead of the default `"gnu"`), via c-set-style. It's been a while since I played with this, so I'll leave it to someone else to answer. It's documented somewhere in the [cc-mode manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/index.html).

Comment: Read this: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Custom-C-Indent.html

Comment: You can use `C-c C-s` to check the syntax as it appears to emacs. Then you can use the function `c-set-offset` to change the indentation for that bit of syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I met this problem before. Here, I recommend you to install a package named `google-c-style`. After finishing this, the only thing you should do is
that put config below into your own init-file.

`(require 'google-c-style)
(defun my-c-mode-hook ()
  (google-set-c-style)
  (setq c-basic-offset 4 
        indent-tabs-mode t 
        default-tab-width 4))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)`

It's my own config.

Additionally, I'm new for emacs two. It's so difficult to find a question that I can help. Thanks for your question!